# CSS make image show out of div

Tags: html, css

What's a good way to have an image (dark gray box) pop over the background at the top while still filling the space down to the end of the background box?

[image: box pops out]

Comment: you will probably need to position it absolutely, but please remind yourself what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Comment: try giving image `max-height:100%, max-width: 100%`

Comment: both of them. position absolute with top - 20% and height 120% (to reach bottom)

Comment: please share some working demo on jsFiddel or codepen or other to look upon.

Comment: There are many ways but it depends on content how you need.. If its just extra space with same bg you can use pseudo code and positioning, if you need whole content you may use padding and positioning..

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to do it in a way that isn't a bit hacky, how would something like this work?

Create a one column for the text and one for the image.

Give the image column `position:relative` then position the image to the bottom minus the container padding.

```css
.offset-container {
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  background-color: #dedede;
  padding: 30px;
}

.text-box {
  width: 46%
}

.image-container {
  width: 46%;
  padding-right: 8%;
  position: relative;
}

.image-offset {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -30px;
}

.responsive-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="offset-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-box">
      <h3>Title Here</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque scelerisque facilisis neque vitae scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img class="image-offset responsive-image" src="http://placehold.it/200x360">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
.container {
position: relative; 
z-index: 0; 
}

.overlap {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  max-height: 100% 100vh; // or whatever you want
  background: url(), no-repeat center center; // if you want it as a bg image
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have created 2 columns one for image and one for text, Use transform scale on the image and add position or negative bottom margin to align the image with the container

```
image {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
}
```